# django ajax request to same site path failing with 403 error

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, post, cookies

My site ( https://www.martinbarker.me/discogstagger ) has a button that when clicked calls a javascript function that makes an ajax post request to the path /my-ajax-test/, which is supposed to call a python function and return some data. It's worked fine in the past but has suddenly stopped working, and I'm trying to debug it to figure out why.

My ajax post request that gets called when the button is pressed looks like this:

```
function makeAjax(dataVar, csrftoken) {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    console.log("making ajax reqeust to get data. header set")
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/my-ajax-test/',
        headers: { 'ACookieAvailableCrossSite': 'SameSite=None' },
        data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken, data: dataVar },
        }).done(function callback(response) {
            console.log("ajax request to /my-ajax-test/ was a success !")
            console.log("response = ", response)
            resolve(JSON.stringify(response))

        }).fail(function (error) {
            console.log("ajax request to /my-ajax-test/ failed!");
            console.log(error)
        });
    });
}
```

When I press this button, I get a 403 error in console like so:

I'm running my site locally to test, before I push changes to where its hosted online (heroku), I'm getting this popup in console that I'm trying to fix:

[image]

The two google errors are from me trying to setup adsense and havent affected my post request before, I printed out my error but I'm not seeing anything that helps me debug this. Is there something I'm missing in my ajax post request with the header to fix the chrome error?

```
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://youtube.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
```

thx

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the function with this and it worked:

```js
    function makeAjax(dataVar, csrftoken) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            console.log("making ajax reqeust to get data. header set")
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/my-ajax-test/',
                headers: { 'ACookieAvailableCrossSite': 'SameSite=None' },
                data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: 'RQ', data: dataVar }, //new csrf
            }).done(function callback(response) {
                console.log("ajax request to /my-ajax-test/ was a success !")
                console.log("response = ", response)
                resolve(JSON.stringify(response))

            }).fail(function (error) {
                console.log("ajax request to /my-ajax-test/ failed!");
                console.log(error)
            });
        });
    }
```